# MySQL select one column DISTINCT, with corresponding other columns

Tags: mysql

```
ID   FirstName   LastName
1      John        Doe
2      Bugs        Bunny
3      John        Johnson
```

I want to select `DISTINCT` results from the `FirstName` column, but I need the corresponding `ID` and `LastName`.

The result set needs to show only one `John`, but with an `ID` of 1 and a `LastName` of Doe.

Comment: You want the last name belonging to the lowest ID with a distinct first name?

Comment: What is the logic that should go into the selection of the top one?  I would think you would want both John Doe and John Johnson to show up since they are two distinct Johns but that is just me.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. All answers with `DISTINCT()` are wrong. The error will show up when you do not place it after `SELECT`.

Comment: `ALL` *answers* using parentheses after the word distinct are indeed wrong. **Distinct is NOT a function** so it cannot accept a parameter. The parentheses following distinct are simply ignored. Unless you are using PostgreSQL where the parentheses will form a "complex data type"

Answer (score 258, accepted):

try this query

```
 SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM table GROUP BY(FirstName)
```

Comment: How do we know which row will be returned?

Comment: @Full Decent you can't, according to MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html): "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.". 
In practice I've successfully used this kind of queries with ORDER BY clause, for instance you could add ORDER BY id ASC/DESC and MySQL would return consistent results every time you would execute the query. But i would be sure whether anyone should use undocumented features in production environment.

Comment: O.P. doesn't mention mysql version.

Comment: I've been searching a lot regarding this issue in MySQL 5.7 and nothing is coming up, seriously!

Comment: @sinaza see my updated answer for MySQL `5.7.5+` for the changed [`GROUP BY` handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: Attention! This is very bad solution for big data. Because GROUP BY sorts through all the lines, but selected only 2-3 rows.

Comment: This doesn't work with only_full_group_by mode because neither ID nor LastName are neither aggregated nor part of the grouping function. Help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58808461/1770571 This is so helpful

Comment: this isn't a good idea if you don't know, only MySql allow this, whereas other SQL languages will throw an error because that is the correct behavior!

Comment: OP ask about MySQL only not for other

Answer (score 103):

To avoid potentially unexpected results when using `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function, *as is used in the accepted answer*, because MySQL is free to retrieve **ANY** value within the data set being grouped when not using an aggregate function [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and issues with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. Please consider using an exclusion join.

### Exclusion Join - Unambiguous Entities

Assuming the firstname and lastname are uniquely indexed *(unambiguous)*, an alternative to `GROUP BY` is to sort using a `LEFT JOIN` to filter the result set, otherwise known as an exclusion JOIN.

[See Demonstration](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9sUujXsXb1inK8zy7BmwaE/0)

**Ascending order *(A-Z)***

To retrieve the distinct firstname ordered by lastname from A-Z

**Query**

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_name AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_name AS t2
ON t1.firstname = t2.firstname
AND t1.lastname > t2.lastname
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

**Result**

```
| id | firstname | lastname |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  2 |      Bugs |    Bunny |
|  1 |      John |      Doe |
```

**Descending order *(Z-A)***

To retrieve the distinct firstname ordered by lastname from Z-A

**Query**

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_name AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_name AS t2
ON t1.firstname = t2.firstname
AND t1.lastname < t2.lastname
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

**Result**

```
| id | firstname | lastname |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  2 |      Bugs |    Bunny |
|  3 |      John |  Johnson |
```

You can then order the resulting data as desired.

---

### Exclusion Join - Ambiguous Entities

If the first and last name combination are not unique *(ambiguous)* and you have multiple rows of the same values, you can filter the result set by including an OR condition on the JOIN criteria to also filter by id.

[See Demonstration](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ddYYo78Fgg7XvoggadvmNg/0)

**table_name data**

```
(1, 'John', 'Doe'),
(2, 'Bugs', 'Bunny'),
(3, 'John', 'Johnson'),
(4, 'John', 'Doe'),
(5, 'John', 'Johnson')
```

**Query**

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_name AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_name AS t2
ON t1.firstname = t2.firstname
AND (t1.lastname > t2.lastname
OR (t1.firstname = t1.firstname AND t1.lastname = t2.lastname AND t1.id > t2.id))
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

**Result**

```
| id | firstname | lastname |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  1 |      John |      Doe |
|  2 |      Bugs |    Bunny |
```

---

### Composite `IN()` Subquery - Unambiguous Entities

For larger datasets, using an exclusion join can be very slow.
If you have unambiguous entries, an alternative is to use a Composite `IN()` criteria against a `MIN/MAX` aggregate subquery.

[Demonstration](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLZBhjE8RetGt8NL1gpVxG/0)

**Ascending Order *(A-Z)***

**Query**

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_name AS t1
WHERE (t1.firstname, t1.lastname) IN(
   SELECT firstname, MIN(lastname)
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY firstname
)
```

**Result**

```
| id | firstname | lastname |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  2 |      Bugs |    Bunny |
|  1 |      John |      Doe |
```

**Descending Order *(Z-A)***

**Query**

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_name AS t1
WHERE (t1.firstname, t1.lastname) IN(
   SELECT firstname, MAX(lastname)
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY firstname
)
```

**Result**

```
| id | firstname | lastname |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  2 |      Bugs |    Bunny |
|  3 |      John |  Johnson |
```

---

### Composite `IN()` Dependent Subquery - Ambiguous Entities

The same theory can be applied from the Ambiguous Exclusion join to the composite `IN()` subquery method, by adding a dependent subquery with `MIN/MAX` on the id column.

[Demonstration](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kCvWsP14r6VmNZqvmWT5ac/0)

**Query**

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_name AS t1
WHERE t1.id IN(
   SELECT MIN(id)
   FROM table_name
   WHERE (t1.firstname, t1.lastname) IN(
      SELECT firstname, MIN(lastname)
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY firstname
   )
   GROUP BY firstname, lastname
);
```

**Result**

```
| id | firstname | lastname |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  1 |      John |      Doe |
|  2 |      Bugs |    Bunny |
```

---

### Ordered Subquery

**EDIT**

My original answer using an ***ordered subquery***, was written prior to **MySQL 5.7.5**, which is no longer applicable, due to the changes with [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).  Please use the one of the examples above instead.

It is also important to note; when `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled *(original behavior prior to MySQL 5.7.5)*, the use of `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function may yield unexpected results, because MySQL is free to choose **ANY** value within the data set being grouped [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Meaning an `ID` or `lastname` value may be retrieved ***that is not associated*** with the retrieved `firstname` row.

---

**WARNING**

With MySQL `GROUP BY` may not yield the expected results when used with `ORDER BY`

[See Test Case Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/stJgoYs65wBDzwHw8AxAmP/0)

The best method of implementation, to ensure expected results, is to filter the result set scope using an ordered subquery.

**table_name data**

```
(1, 'John', 'Doe'),
(2, 'Bugs', 'Bunny'),
(3, 'John', 'Johnson')
```

**Query**

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC
) AS t1
GROUP BY FirstName
```

**Result (MySQL 5.6)**

```
| ID | first |    last |
|----|-------|---------|
|  2 |  Bugs |   Bunny |
|  3 |  John | Johnson |
```

---

**Comparison**

To demonstrate the unexpected results when using `GROUP BY` in combination with `ORDER BY`

**Query**

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY FirstName ORDER BY ID DESC
```

**Result (MySQL 5.6)**

```
| ID | first |  last |
|----|-------|-------|
|  2 |  Bugs | Bunny |
|  1 |  John |   Doe |
```

Comment: Most complete answer by far. Changing 'ID desc' to 'ID asc' in the first query allow us to retrieve either 'John  Doe' or 'John Johnson'. Changing 'ID desc' in second query does'nt have this effect.

Comment: On postgres you need ID in group by not sure of mysql.

Comment: Will a GROUP BY column-A ORDER BY column-B in one SELECT statement always work correctly with latest version of MyriaDB?

Comment: @NealDavis As per **MariaDB** manual `Ordering is done after grouping.`, so No not in this use-case, in addition [MariaDB ignores ORDER BY in subqueries](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/) 
(as per the SQL standard) without a `LIMIT`. You would want to use a [`Window Function`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/) For more clarification you should ask your question in the [DBA stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com), as this is a question relating to MySQL

Comment: To be clear, is it safe to use a subquery with `order by` and then `group by`, as in your section labeled `WARNING`?

Comment: @NateS No, the `GROUP BY` can select any value within the grouped data set, 
unless an aggregate function is used on those columns to force a specific value. So `lastname` or `id` can come from any of the ordered rows. The original subquery example was acceptable by default in `MySQL <= 5.7.4` but technically still suffers from the issue. While the `ORDER BY` does help to prevent a random selection, it is still theoretically possible, but with a significantly less probability than without using the `ORDER BY` subquery.

Answer (score 81):

The `DISTINCT` keyword doesn't really work the way you're expecting it to. When you use `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3` you are in fact selecting all unique {col1, col2, col3} tuples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Brian. Can you provide an example of how I could utilize GROUP BY to obtain the same results?

Answer (score 24):

```
SELECT ID,LastName 
From TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY FirstName 
HAVING COUNT(*) >=1
```

Comment: adding `HAVING` made my query 50% slower.

Comment: Is there any case in which HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1 will be false?

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
SELECT 
    my_distinct_column,
    max(col1),
    max(col2),
    max(col3)
    ...
 FROM
    my_table 
 GROUP BY 
    my_distinct_column`
```

Comment: The issue with using an aggregate function on multiple columns from a single column grouping, is that `MAX()` will retrieve the highest value within the groupings, instead of the corresponding row values of the distinct column that the OP is wanting. [Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJ8gtnSntvKcv31mgWWY9o/0) expects `5, John, Johnson` but receives `6, John, Johnson` where `ID 6` is `John, Doe`

Comment: I upvoted the answer but I didn't see that I got wrong results like @Will says. This way you get 'fake' rows with a mix of values from every group. Change MAX() to SUM() to understand it better. (I can't uncheck the upvote)

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by [fyrye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144627/fyrye), the accepted answer pertains to older versions of MySQL in which [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) had not yet been introduced. With MySQL 8.0.17 (used in this example), unless you disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` you would get the following error message:

```
mysql> SELECT id, firstName, lastName FROM table_name GROUP BY firstName;
```

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mydatabase.table_name.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

One way to work around this not mentioned by [fyrye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144627/fyrye), but described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html, is to apply the [`ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) function to the columns which are not in the `GROUP BY` clause (`id` and `lastName` in this example):

```
mysql> SELECT ANY_VALUE(id) as id, firstName, ANY_VALUE(lastName) as lastName FROM table_name GROUP BY firstName;
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | firstName | lastName |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | John      | Doe      |
|  2 | Bugs      | Bunny    |
+----+-----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

As written in the aforementioned docs,

> In this case, MySQL ignores the nondeterminism of address values within each name group and accepts the query. This may be useful if you simply do not care which value of a nonaggregated column is chosen for each group. `ANY_VALUE()` is not an aggregate function, unlike functions such as `SUM()` or `COUNT()`. It simply acts to suppress the test for nondeterminism.

Comment: For clarification, I specifically avoided suggesting to use `ANY_VALUE()` as my answer and comments are focused on preventing ambiguous and unpredictable result-sets. Since as the function name suggests, it could result in any value from the selected rows being retrieved. I would suggest using `MAX` or `MIN` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT firstName, ID, LastName from tableName GROUP BY firstName
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can do this with MySQL, but you can use a CTE in T-SQL

```
; WITH tmpPeople AS (
 SELECT 
   DISTINCT(FirstName),
   MIN(Id)      
 FROM People
)
SELECT
 tP.Id,
 tP.FirstName,
 P.LastName
FROM tmpPeople tP
JOIN People P ON tP.Id = P.Id
```

Otherwise you might have to use a temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind when using the group by and order by that MySQL is the ONLY database that allows for columns to be used in the group by and/or order by piece that are not part of the select statement.

So for example:
select column1
from table
group by column2
order by column3

That will not fly in other databases like Postgres, Oracle, MSSQL, etc.  You would have to do the following in those databases

select column1, column2, column3
from table
group by column2
order by column3

Just some info in case you ever migrate your current code to another database or start working in another database and try to reuse code.

Answer (score -2):

You can use group by for display distinct values and also corresponding fields.

```
select * from tabel_name group by FirstName
```

Now you got output like this:

```
ID    FirstName     LastName
2     Bugs          Bunny
1     John          Doe
```

If you want to answer like

```
ID    FirstName     LastName
1     John          Doe
2     Bugs          Bunny
```

then use this query,

```
select * from table_name group by FirstName order by ID
```

Comment: This will not always yield expected results when grouping with order by

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(firstName), ID, LastName from tableName GROUP BY firstName
```

Would be the best bet IMO

Comment: this won't work, it will also take the ID and lastname into the distinct evaluation.

Comment: this is same as DISTINCT(firstName, ID, LastName)

Answer (score -5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (column1), column2
FROM table1
GROUP BY column1
```

Comment: `DISTINCT()` is not a function. Also DISTINCT and GROUP BY are doing the same thing, so no reason put them both.

Comment: This is not an efficient statement, you should use either DISTINCT or Group By not both.