# Right way to use distinct in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to retrieve some records based on the query

```
Select distinct 
    tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.AssessmentEcosystemCreditID,
    tblSpecies.CommonName 
from 
    tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit
left join 
    tblSpeciesVegTypeLink on tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.VegTypeID = tblSpeciesVegTypeLink.VegTypeID 
left join 
    tblSpecies on tblSpecies.SpeciesID = tblSpeciesVegTypeLink.SpeciesID
where 
    tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.SpeciesTGValue < 1
```

The above query returns 17,000 records but when I remove `tblSpecies.CommonName`, it retrieves only 4200 (that's actually correct).

I have no idea how to distinct only `tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.AssessmentEcosystemCreditID` column and retrieve all other table columns in the query.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: Ooops sorry, i thought selected only SQL server

Comment: See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns

Comment: @JonasB, i tired what they advised but i got an exception "Column 'tblSpecies.CommonName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: This query selects the different COMBINATION of AssessmentEcosystemCreditID  and CommonName; if you want only one row per value of AssessmentEcosystemCreditID then you need to use a GROUP BY, as suggested by @JonasB; however, in that case, there could be several values of CommonName per value of AssessmentEcosystemCreditID , and so SQL requires you to specify WHICH one you want.

Comment: ... and the easiest way to select which one you want is wrap it in an aggregate function like MIN or MAX..... which will pick the alphabetically first or last one. If that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query selects the different COMBINATION of AssessmentEcosystemCreditID and CommonName; if you want only one row per value of AssessmentEcosystemCreditID then you need to use a GROUP BY, as suggested by @JonasB; however, in that case, there could be several values of CommonName per value of AssessmentEcosystemCreditID , and so SQL requires you to specify WHICH one you want

```
Select  tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.AssessmentEcosystemCreditID ,
         max(tblSpecies.CommonName) as CommonName,
         min(tblSpecies.CommonName) as CommonName2, -- so you can verify you only have one value
 from tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit
 left join tblSpeciesVegTypeLink 
      on tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.VegTypeID = tblSpeciesVegTypeLink.VegTypeID 
 left join tblSpecies on tblSpecies.SpeciesID= tblSpeciesVegTypeLink.SpeciesID
 where tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.SpeciesTGValue <1
 GROUP BY tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.AssessmentEcosystemCreditID
```

Answer (score 1):

See this topic: [mySQL select one column DISTINCT, with corresponding other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns)

You probably have to deactivate ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by