# Cakphpe DISTINCT not working with multiple fields

Tags: cakephp

I have write down this query

```
pr($this->User->find('all',array('fields'=>array('DISTINCT User.last_name','User.first_name')))); die;

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [last_name] => singh
                    [first_name] => admin
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [last_name] => singh
                    [first_name] => jaskaran
                )

        )

)
```

It is not working but when i remove first_name from fields then it is work

```
pr($this->User->find('all',array('fields'=>array('DISTINCT User.last_name')))); die;
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [last_name] => singh
                )

        )

)
```

but i need both field with distinct cakephp 2+

Comment: What do you expect to happen? That looks like the results of a `DISTINCT`

Comment: I have mention there what i want, When i pass 2 fields in array then Distinct not working

Comment: What do you want your final result to look like? You are not clearly explaining what you want: Put in your question what you want the final result to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to retrieve  `last_name` & `firstname` from user table where `lastname` is `DISTINCT`.

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('User.last_name', 'User.first_name'),
    'group' => array('User.firstname')
));
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [last_name] => singh
                    [first_name] => admin
                )

        )

)
```

Just look the following [mySQL select one column DISTINCT, with corresponding other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns)