# MySQL 5.7 return all columns of table based on distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I just upgraded to MySQL 5.7 and unfortunately for me, some of the functionality of `GROUP BY` is gone. I wanted to select all movies from my `movies` table with as long as the `movies.id` of type `int` is not a duplicate. My previous query in MySQL 5.6 was:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE movies.title LIKE '%example%'
GROUP BY movies.id
```

If I had two movies with the same id, it would only display one movie, instead of that movie and its duplicates.

When I upgraded to MySQL 5.7, the `GROUP BY` gave me errors and I was instead told to use `ORDER BY`. However this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE movies.title LIKE '%example%'
ORDER BY movies.id
```

Does return duplicate movies. So, is there a way to filter this out, and only return a row if it isn't a duplicate?

Edit: For example if this is my `movies` table:

```
movies
==================
|  id  |   title  |
==================
| 1    | example  |
------------------
| 2    | example  |
------------------
| 1    | example  |
------------------
```

Here is the output of each query:

```
Previous query result (with MySQL 5.6)
=======
1 | example
2 | example

New query result (with MySQL 5.7 and ORDER BY)
=======
1 | example
1 | example
2 | example
```

I want the final result to contain no duplicates (so the result should look like the first query result).

Edit 2: I understand I was sort of abusing the way MySQL handled `GROUP BY`. Unfortunately, I do not have much experience with MySQL and got that answer from StackOverflow. I would just like to return all columns in my table that do not contain duplicate `id`s.

Comment: Why do you have duplicate movies? If you have no PRIMARY KEY then, as far as the RDBMS is concerned, you have no table.

Comment: @Strawberry This is for an assignment in school. We were purposefully given bad data for the assignment. :| Unfortunately it is up to us to return non-duplicate rows. Everything did work fine until 5.7.. but I can't downgrade because I need some of the newer features that it provides.

Comment: GROUP BY is intended to work with aggregate functions. SELECT DISTINCT is intended for use where no aggregation is required.

Comment: @Strawberry From what I understand, I was sort of abusing the way MySQL 5.6 worked, unknowingly (I got the `GROUP BY` thing from an answer on stack overflow). I would really just like to return all rows that do not contain duplicate ids.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function. (Older MySQL versions didn't care about this, and instead returned an arbitrary result.)

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: @jarlh From my understanding you can not `SELECT DISTINCT` on just one column and still retrieve all of the columns ([found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns)). If there is a way to `SELECT DISTINCT` on only one column while returning all other columns how would I be able to do that?

Comment: Correct, it works on the whole selected rows. In your case you will get two rows, (1, example) and (2, example). Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @jarlh Doing `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM movies WHERE movies.title = 'example'` returns non-distinct rows for some reason. Ie. it returns the duplicate id `1` and the duplicate title `example`.

Comment: Are your movies called `example`, or something else...?

Comment: @jarlh It's a search that uses the `LIKE` predicate. So the actual example is `SELECT DISTINCT movies.* FROM movies WHERE movies.title LIKE %term%`. This ends up returning duplicates. Sorry about that, I didn't realize the `LIKE` predicate might affect the distinct results.

Comment: LIKE has nothing to do with SELECT DISTINCT. Are you getting duplicate rows when SELECT DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

I believe would be easy to use `distinct` keyword

```
SELECT distinct movies.*
FROM movies 
WHERE movies.title = 'example'
```