# Django query: get the last entries of all distinct values by list

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to make a Django query for getting a list of the last entries for each distinct values from a `MySQL` database. I will show an example below as this explanation can be very complicated. Getting the distinct values by themselves obviously in Django is no problem using `.values()`. I was thinking to create couple of Django queries but that looks to be cumbersome. Is there an easy way of doing this.

For the example below. Suppose I want the rows with distinct Names with their last entry(latest date).

```
Name            email                 date
_________________________________________________

Dane            dane@yahoo.com        2017-06-20
Kim             kim@gmail.com         2017-06-10
Hong            hong@gmail.com        2016-06-25
Dane            dddd@gmail.com        2017-06-04
Susan           Susan@gmail.com       2017-05-21
Dane            kkkk@gmail.com        2017-02-01
Susan           sss@gmail.com         2017-05-20
```

All the distinct values are Dane, kim, Hong, Susan. I also want the rows with the latest dates associated with these distinct name. The list with entries I would like is the rows below. Notice Names are all distinct, and they are associated with the latest date.

```
 Name            email                 date
_________________________________________________

Dane            dane@yahoo.com        2017-06-20
Kim             kim@gmail.com         2017-06-10
Hong            hong@gmail.com        2016-06-25
Susan           Susan@gmail.com       2017-05-21
```

Answer (score 3):

with postgresql you should able to do:

```
 EmailModel.objects.all().order_by('date').distinct('Name')
```

for more methods/functions like this, you can visit [the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets)

Comment: This does not work, but I am following your input, as it looks like it is going in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: yes its not exact code. it depends on your EmailModel looks like

Comment: It does not work. django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: How to apply filtering over it? for ex- i don't want to include it in the result if the first email id is dane@yahoo.com for Dave and only include it if it is something different.

Answer (score 1):

This only applies to POSTGRES

You can use the `ORDER_BY` command to set your query set as ordered by date, then chain with the `DISTINCT` command to get distinct rows and specify which field. The `DISTINCT` command will take the first entry for each name. Refer [The Docs For More](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

**Edit**

For MYSQL, you will have to use raw SQL queries, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns)

Comment: Thank you sir, but I am using `MySQL`. I will keep playing around with it. Come to think of it I was using `order_by` and ran into some command line problem on the `Python` console

Answer (score 1):

Only `Postgres` supports providing field names in `distinct`. Also, any field provided in `values` and `order_by` is in distinct, thus providing ambiguous results sometimes.

However for MySQL:

```
Model.objects.values('names').distinct().latest('date')
```