# mysql - group by part of the rows

Tags: mysql, database

Using mysql, Suppose my table looks like this:

```
| id | name   | type  
| 1  | name1  | type 1
| 2  | name2  | type 2
| 3  | name3  | type 2
| 4  | name4  | type 3
| 5  | name4  | type 4
| 6  | name5  | type 2
| 7  | name6  | type 3
```

I'd like to get all the rows from the table and group all of type 2 into  a single row.
 In this example it doesn't matter if the row is id 2 or 3.

The result should look like this:

```
    | id | name   | type  
    | 1  | name1  | type 1
    | 3  | name3  | type 2
    | 4  | name4  | type 3
    | 5  | name4  | type 4
    | 7  | name6  | type 3
```

Comment: You can't.... If you group rows in `type` column, you won't be able to see ALL the other rows from `id` and/or `name` if they have the same value AND you won't have a grouped `type` if they have different column... Anyways the query for grouping would be : `select id,name,type from your_table group by type ;`

Comment: Hmmm @JasonKrs's comment just appeared. But indeed, like he said, just `group by type`. Might also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns) and/or the [`DISTINCT` reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) - might apply to what you're trying to do, not sure ;)

Comment: If I group by type, I won't get id 4 or 5. I want to get all the row and group only type 2.

Comment: Ok I think I may understand what you want

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to solve a (different) problem, but asking about how to execute the solution you are thinking of, instead of asking how to solve the original problem in a maybe different way (an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @Solarflare  Looking at the answer I posted and your comment I think I actually (eventually lol) understood his request

Comment: @Jason yes, his request is probably what you understood, but I am not sure if it is a good request in the sense that it solves his underlying problem (I assume he wants to hide parts of the data, like the "+" in programming ides to hide a procedure or a loop and just show the header), so he might want to add his underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a result set with just one row for each value of `type`.  Your sample table shows three different rows with a  `type` of `type 2`, and one each of several other `type` values.

This query returns one row per `type` showing the row with the largest `id` value for each type.  If `id` is an autoincrementing primary key, this means it shows the *most recently inserted* row with that type. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f8c54/3/0)

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.type
  FROM tbl a
  JOIN (
              SELECT MAX(id) id
                FROM tbl
               GROUP BY type
       ) m ON a.id = m.id
 GROUP BY type
```

You can change the subquery (`SELECT MAX(id)...`) to choose an appropriate row for your application. For example `MIN(id)` gives the *least recently inserted* row.

If you only want to do that data-reduction operation for one value of `type`, you'll need a UNION to recover the detail rows from the other `type` values. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f8c54/8/0)

```
SELECT * 
 FROM (
    SELECT a.id, a.name, a.type
      FROM tbl a
      JOIN (
                  SELECT MAX(id) id
                    FROM tbl
                   GROUP BY type
           ) m ON a.id = m.id
     WHERE type = 'type 2'
     GROUP BY type
     UNION
    SELECT id, name, type
      FROM tbl
     WHERE type <> 'type 2'
   ) q
ORDER BY type, id
```