# How to select from records with bigger id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this,

```
     Select * from customers c join invoice I on
     c.id = i.customerid where c.date = '12-12-2019' and i.date = '12-12-2019'
```

The result is as follows

```
+------------+--------------+---------+-------+
| Customerid | customername | address | phone |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------+
| 1          | Peter        | Flat a  | 4567  |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------+
| 2          | Peter        | Flat a  | 4567  |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------+ 
| 5          | John         | Flat b  | 1234  |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------+
| 6          | John         | Flat b  | 1234  |
+------------+--------------+---------+-------+
```

The query will get the record with small customerid. How can I force the query to select the record with bigger customerid?

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: `ORDER BY customerid DESC` will get the records with the highest customer ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL select one column DISTINCT, with corresponding other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What results do you want returned?

Comment: Please note that your IDs should not be meaningful.  Why do you want the rows with an ID with a higher value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the question I flagged as duplicate, you can use an exclusion join to filter your record set to retrieve the desired results.

Exclusion joins work by joining the same table and retrieving only the records with the greatest `Customerid`. Additionally it will not suffer from `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` issues and does not require using `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY`, which can produce undesirable results if used incorrectly.

### Exclusion Join [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kkfjHyvx8LJxbDUX5apKW1/0)

```sql
SELECT c1.*
FROM customers AS c1
LEFT JOIN customers AS c2
ON c2.customername = c1.customername
AND c2.customerid > c1.customerid
WHERE c2.customerid IS NULL;
```

**Result**

```
| Customerid | customername | address | phone |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------- | ----- |
| 2          | Peter        | Flat a  | 4567  |
| 6          | John         | Flat b  | 1234  |
```

### Ambiguous Exclusion Join

In the event that `customername` is not unique to a single entity (is ambiguous), you can include additional criteria to the exclusion join, to ensure the correct entity is retrieved.

```sql
LEFT JOIN customers AS c2
ON c2.customername = c1.customername
AND c2.address = c1.address
AND c2.phone = c1.phone
AND c2.customerid > c1.customerid
WHERE c2.customerid IS NULL;
```

---

### Exclusion Join Expansion [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kvcMmsYtA1DxnULqz5Xy9n/0)

You can then expand your statement with additional joins to retrieve records with the bigger `customers.Customerid`.

Given the following table data-sets and you want to display the `customers.Customerid` with `2`, and `6`

*customers*

```sql
| Customerid | customername | address | phone | date       |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------- | ----- | ---------- |
| 1          | Peter        | Flat a  | 4567  | 12-12-2019 |
| 2          | Peter        | Flat a  | 4567  | 12-12-2019 |
| 5          | John         | Flat b  | 1234  | 12-12-2019 |
| 6          | John         | Flat b  | 1234  | 12-12-2019 |
```

*invoice*

```sql
| Invoiceid | Customerid | date       |
| --------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1         | 1          | 12-12-2019 |
| 2         | 2          | 12-12-2019 |
| 3         | 5          | 12-12-2019 |
| 4         | 5          | 12-12-2019 |
| 5         | 6          | 12-12-2019 |
```

**Query**

```sql
SELECT c1.*, I.*
FROM customers AS c1
LEFT JOIN customers AS c2
ON c2.customername = c1.customername
AND c2.customerid > c1.customerid
INNER JOIN invoice I
ON c1.customerid = I.Customerid 
AND I.date = c1.date
WHERE c1.date = '12-12-2019'
AND c2.customerid IS NULL;
```

This will *"force the query to select the record with bigger customerid?"* of those also within `invoice` table.

Additionally I removed the redundant criteria `c.date = '12-12-2019' and i.date = '12-12-2019'` in favor of using `I.date = c1.date` in the INNER JOIN criteria.

I do not understand the purpose of `customers.date`, as usually invoices match to the customer that was invoiced, and the invoice dates entered are variable. So I believe that `c.date = '12-12-2019'` can be omitted in favor of using `INNER JOIN invoice I
ON c1.id = I.customerid AND I.date = '12-12-2019'`, in order to retrieve the invoices with the desired date and the associated customer that was invoiced.

**Query Alternative**

```sql
SELECT c1.*, I.*
FROM customers AS c1
LEFT JOIN customers AS c2
ON c2.customername = c1.customername
AND c2.customerid > c1.customerid
INNER JOIN invoice I
ON c1.customerid = I.Customerid 
AND I.date = '12-12-2019'
WHERE c2.customerid IS NULL;
```

**Result**

```
| Customerid | customername | address | phone | date       | Invoiceid | Customerid | date       |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------- | ----- | ---------- | --------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 2          | Peter        | Flat a  | 4567  | 12-12-2019 | 2         | 2          | 12-12-2019 |
| 6          | John         | Flat b  | 1234  | 12-12-2019 | 5         | 6          | 12-12-2019 |
```

---

### Considerations

It is important to note that your original statement `join invoice I on c.id = i.customerid WHERE c.date = '12-12-2019' and i.date = '12-12-2019'`,  only matches records from the `invoice` table with the same `customerid` and `date` in the `customers` table.

The query I provided forces retrieval of only customers with the bigger `customers.Customerid`. It does not match the invoice customer to the bigger Customerid, in other-words it will not retrieve  the `customers.Customerid = 2` when `invoice.Customerid = 1`.

If you are wanting to display the bigger `customers.Customerid` for associated invoices, please leave a comment and update your question to clarify along with providing a sample data-set with a desired end-result. However, I believe if that is the case, it is an indication of a relational design flaw in your database structure and may result in data-integrity issues in the long-term.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7XxJfdoajp6nGipuFuWEk5/0). you can write below query on the top of your main query.

```
select
    max(customerId) as customerId,
    customerName,
    address,
    phone
from customers
group by
    customerName,
    address,
    phone
order by 
    customerId
```

Output:

```
| customerId | customerName | address | phone |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------- | ----- |
| 2          | Peter        | Flat a  | 4567  |
| 6          | John         | Flat b  | 1234  |
```