# MySQL getting data of max other column for each groups

Tags: mysql

The table seems

```
group_id   | time              | data  | others...
1           2020-11-30 12:00:00 13
1           2020-11-30 13:00:00 15
2           2020-11-30 12:30:00 254
3           2021-02-21 18:00:00 25565
...
```

I wanted to get the "data" of "latest time"(which can be different for each group) for each group specified,

so I wrote down like

```
SELECT group_id, max(time), data
where group_id between (...)
(and others = ...)
group by group_id
```

but It's data was not the value of that time (actually seems like the latest record)

How can I get the data of maximum time for each group?

Comment: Does your table have a primary key column?

Comment: How do you plan to break ties in the case where there are 2 or more rows in the same group with the same `time`?

Comment: surely the table has primary key on (group_id, time) so It would be okay

Comment: When not using an aggregate function, MySQL is free to retrieve any value from the non grouped columns (data), which usually is the first or last record, depending on index. You would need to filter the result set by the `MAX(time)` and determine a sorting for the `data` column.  This is generally done with an exclusion join, [when looking to obtain distinct values (min/max) with corresponding other values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns/26124759#26124759).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a primary key on `group_id, time`, you can use a standard exclusion join, as opposed to a `GROUP BY`, since the records are unambiguous.

In this instance to obtain the `group_id` and `MAX(time)` with the corresponding other values you would `LEFT JOIN table AS b ON a.group_id = b.group_id AND a.time < b.time` Then remove the undesired entries by filtering the left join table results with `WHERE b.group_id IS NULL`

### Exclusion Join

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e8hGEpRawFoMhrhd32C295/0)

```sql
SELECT t1.group_id, t1.`time`, t1.`data`
FROM `table` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `table` AS t2
ON t2.group_id = t1.`group_id` 
AND t1.`time` < t2.`time`
WHERE t1.group_id BETWEEN ...
AND t1.others = ...
AND t2.group_id IS NULL;
```

Result:

```
| group_id | time                | data  |
| -------- | ------------------- | ----- |
| 1        | 2020-11-30 13:00:00 | 15    |
| 2        | 2020-11-30 12:30:00 | 254   |
| 3        | 2021-02-21 18:00:00 | 25565 |
```

---

Alternatively, since you have `group_id, time` as your primary key, you can use a compound `IN` subquery criteria with the `MAX(time)`.

### Compound `IN` Subquery

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p51VbzXcyfmeQVbbu9MBjq/0)

```sql
SELECT t1.group_id, t1.`time`, t1.`data`
FROM `table` AS t1
WHERE t1.others = ....
AND (t1.group_id, t1.`time`) IN(
   SELECT group_id, MAX(`time`)
   FROM `table`
   WHERE group_id BETWEEN ....
   GROUP BY group_id
);
```

Result:

```
| group_id | time                | data  |
| -------- | ------------------- | ----- |
| 1        | 2020-11-30 13:00:00 | 15    |
| 2        | 2020-11-30 12:30:00 | 254   |
| 3        | 2021-02-21 18:00:00 | 25565 |
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tested these two way and found that LEFT JOIN with nullable huge much cost! so I applied INNER JOIN method which use Compound at ON clause and it did the best performance whatever I did.

Answer (score 0):

I myself found answer for this using JOIN

```
with tmp as (
SELECT group_id, max(time) as time FROM table
WHERE group_id between (...)
(and others = ...)
group by group_id
)
SELECT r.data FROM table as r
INNER JOIN tmp ON r.group_id = tmp.group_id and r.time = tmp.time
where group_id between (...)
(and others = ...)
```