# Is there a way to return all columns when using distinct?

Tags: sql, distinct

pleeease help!

I need the highest kilometers value and all other related columns from each distinct VehicleId where SalesAgreementID is 10062 from the table below.

[image: tblSalesAgreementDetail]

The result should look something like this:

```
SalesAgreementDetailId | SalesAgreementId | VehicleType | VehicleId | Kilometers | Price
166                    | 10062            | 123         | 000051    | 17377      | 28500.00
169                    | 10062            | 123         | 990140    | 24924      | 28500.00
```

Tried using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VehicleId FROM tblSaleAgreementDetail WHERE SaleAgreementID = '10062';
```

But it didn't return all the other columns I need including the highest kms.

```
VehicleId |
000051    |
990140    |
```

Thaaaankuuu!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL select one column DISTINCT, with corresponding other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could do this:

```
select * from tbl where  id = 'xxx' group by field
```

or this.

```
select distinct on field * from table
```

Comment: Where field is? I get a syntax error on both: 
Column 'tblSaleAgreementDetail.SaleAgreementDetailId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What we usually do, is to rank rows by desired column (`kilometers`) in descending order and optionally restrict (partition) them by *something* (vehicle, in this case). That's what analytic functions are for.

What's left is to select values that rank the "highest".

Something like this:

```
SQL>   with hikm as
  2    (select t.*,
  3       rank() over (partition by vehicleid order by kilometers desc) rnk
  4     from test t
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from hikm
  8  where rnk = 1;

SALEAGREEMENTDETAILID SALEAGREEMENTID VEHICLETYPE VEHICL KILOMETERS        RNK
--------------------- --------------- ----------- ------ ---------- ----------
                  166           10062         123 000051      17377          1
                  169           10062         123 990140      24924          1

SQL>
```